# Decrease string length in pattern

Tags: bash

I have a string like so:

```
text1;text2;text3;text4;text5;text6
```

and i need to decrease length of string after 3rd occurrence ; so in that case

```
text
```

, to for example 4 characters.

so far i did:

```
echo "$(cat pp.txt | awk -F ";" '{print $4}' | sed 's/^\(...\).*/\1/;q' )"
```

But the output is "text". What i need is:

`Text1;text2;text3;text;text5;text6`

Please help

Comment: and i need to decrease length of string after 3rd occurrence ; so in that case

text4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it all with `awk` like

```
awk -F\; 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {$4=substr($4, 0, 4); print}' pp.txt
```

You can modify the fields in `awk`, which we do with `$4=substr($4, 0, 4)`.  That will take the substring of `$4` from the 0th to the 4th characters, then store that back into the forth field.  Then we just print the line with the updated value.

Also, set the output field separator to be the same as the one we specify on the command line so we don't change that when printing it.

Comment: Yep, that does the job!, thank you. One question, what is this - BEGIN {OFS=FS}

Comment: @CharlieBondurant I was just updating my answer as you asked, it sets the output field separator to be the same as the field separator when parsing the line, that way when we print it out it keeps the semi colons in place